# Phonegap 3.0 PowerManagement

Tags: ios, cordova

Is it possible to use the PowerManagement Phonegap Plugin found here https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/29 with Phonegap 3.0 on iOS6,7?

If so, is it still enough to place the following element to the config.xml?

```
<gap:plugin name="com.simplec.plugins.powermanagement" />
```

Or is there a way to install it the Phonegap 3.0 way messes up the iOS version of the app:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/simplec-dev/powermanagement.git
```

What I want to achive is, that my app runs endless and the iPhone power saver gets suppressed.

Thanks for a hint.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the original author has updated the plugin to be compatible with PhoneGap 3.0 yet - but I maintain a fork of it that I have updated that should work. It lives [here](https://github.com/cemerson/cordova-powermanagement) but you should be able to install from the CLI like this:

```
$ cordova plugins add https://github.com/cemerson/cordova-powermanagement.git
```

Also, I'm not sure how recently you've used the plugin but the syntax/usage has changed over the past months/year. I have a few helper scripts that I normally use [here](https://github.com/cemerson/common/blob/master/mobile.js#L743-L771) if you want to modify/use.

PS: Naturally if the original author has updated the plugin somewhere to be 3.0 compliant definitely use that version! Use the above only if that's not the case or you have other problems!

Comment: I'm going to try out your suggestion here as well, but does anyone have experience using plugins found at this repo?
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/PowerManagement
it looks as if it has been updated to v 3.0 of cordova

Answer (score 0):

Cordova plugin PowerManagament for 3.0+

https://github.com/raulduran/PowerManagement